# SQL CLR triggers with Azure Event Hub

Tags: sql-server-2014, assemblies, sqlclr, azure-eventhub

Is there any way to implement change data capture on SQL to Azure EventHub without using exe?

The code needs to run in the context of SQL Server only

SQL Server Version : 2014

Tried SQL CLR with Azure EventHub but not able to create all required assemblies on SQL database.

I'm trying to create the list of references by clicking adding new assemblies on SQL databases. These are the assembly references required as per my Visual Studio project

[image]

But adding one it requires another one and it seems end less. I'm not able to find all the assemblies on my system and i got few assemblies from internet. Many assemblies are added as UNSAFE. While I'm adding, getting always unsafe warning. After lot of struggles added only these assemblies

[image]

Comment: When you say you cannot create all required assemblies - what error do you get?

Comment: Hi Niels Berglund, 

Thanks for you reply, 

I'm trying to create the list of references by clicking adding new assemblies on SQL databases. 

These are the assembly references required as per my Visual Studio project, https://www.screencast.com/t/tUpmWKio 
But adding one it requires another one and it seems end less. I'm not able to find all the assemblies on my system and i got few assemblies from internet. Many assemblies are added as UNSAFE. While I'm adding, getting always unsafe warning. After lot of struggles added only these assemblies, 
https://www.screencast.com/t/3Q5ZZ1YYxZ6

Comment: @msmahasm Is/was this for stand-alone / on-prem SQL Server, or for Azure SQL DB or Managed Instance? I don't think you can add Assemblies to Azure Single DB, so probably not there, correct? Either way, you can only add pure MSIL Assemblies to SQL Server; you are not allowed (i.e. can't do it regardless of permissions) to add mixed-mode assemblies (i.e. those with both managed and unmanaged code in them). I suspect that the assemblies that did not get loaded were either a) reference assemblies (no actual code in them), or b) mixed-mode assemblies. Did you get any farther on this?